# Mongodb Find for Retrieving the Closest Larger / Closest Smaller Values from a List when there is No Exact Match?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection with filed memory with values like (1,7,3.5,5) etc with user query parameter for memory contains 2, the query result should be (1,3.5) to nearest matching value.

Answer (score 0):

for More Information please check https://gist.github.com/anandof86/5433086